# Sort a list of dictionaries which contains list's dicts value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, arraylist

I am building a simple app and I am trying to get json response from `api` But it doesn't have a sort method so I am trying to sort it after fetch in python function, But the problem is that, It is not sorting the list dict.

function.py

```
json_data = [
    {
        "instanceId": "19",
        "instanceData": [
            {
                "blogLikes": "166647",
                "blogComments": "7713",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "instanceId": "3",
        "instanceData": [
            {
                "blogLikes": "236655",
                "blogComments": "8304",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "instanceId": "17",
        "instanceData": [
            {
                "blogLikes": "246865",
                "blogComments": "7213",
            }
        ]
    }
]



def sort_dict(json_data):
    new_dict = sorted(json_data, key=lambda k: k[-1]['instanceData'][0]['blogLikes'])
    print(new_dict)

    return JsonResponse({"example": "nothing"})
```

When I try to run the above function but it is showing

> KeyError at /sort_dict/
> -1

I have tried many times by different method like :-

```
newlist = sorted(json_data, key=lambda d: d['instanceData'])
```

then it showed me

> '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'

Then I tried

```
newlist = sorted(json_data, key=lambda d: list(d.keys()))
```

It didn't raise any error But it returns unexpected result not sorted list.

**What I am trying to do ?**

I am trying to sort above list's dict's according to **blogLikes**

like :-

```
json_data = [
    {
        "instanceId": "17",
        "instanceData": [
            {
                "blogLikes": "246865",
                "blogComments": "7213",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "instanceId": "3",
        "instanceData": [
            {
                "blogLikes": "236655",
                "blogComments": "8304",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "instanceId": "19",
        "instanceData": [
            {
                "blogLikes": "166647",
                "blogComments": "7713",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the purpose of `k[-1]`? Also, if you want it sorted in descending order you need `reverse=True`:

```
json_data = [
    {
        "instanceId": "19",
        "instanceData": [
            {
                "blogLikes": "166647",
                "blogComments": "7713",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "instanceId": "3",
        "instanceData": [
            {
                "blogLikes": "236655",
                "blogComments": "8304",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "instanceId": "17",
        "instanceData": [
            {
                "blogLikes": "246865",
                "blogComments": "7213",
            }
        ]
    }
]



def sort_dict(json_data):
    new_dict = sorted(json_data, key=lambda k: k['instanceData'][0]['blogLikes'], reverse=True)
    print(new_dict)

sort_dict(json_data)
```

output

```
[{'instanceId': '17', 'instanceData': [{'blogLikes': '246865', 'blogComments': '7213'}]}, {'instanceId': '3', 'instanceData': [{'blogLikes': '236655', 'blogComments': '8304'}]}, {'instanceId': '19', 'instanceData': [{'blogLikes': '166647', 'blogComments': '7713'}]}]
```

Note, I keep it as close to your code as possible - e.g. I would return from the function instead of print inside it.

Comment: It is showing `string indices must be integers`

Comment: You've made a mistake somewhere - it works. I will edit my post to include the whole code

Comment: I have checked it many times, and Again I just copy/pasted it, But still showing that error. Is it working in your machine ?

Comment: If this is JSON - make sure that you deserialise it

Comment: You mean like `json.dumps(json_data)`  ?

Comment: No, that would create JSON. If `json_data` is JSON string, you need to `load()` or `loads()` to make it dict. I start to guess this new error is somewhere else in your code

Comment: I tried exactly `.loads()` but it showed `JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list`. Sorry I am beginner in python

Comment: so josn_data is list - no need to do anything

Comment: Just to confirm, this code works just fine.